# Liferay Document Management System Workflow

Tags: liferay, workflow, dms

I am creating a DMS in Liferay. So far I could upload documents in Liferay in document library. And also I can see documents in document and media portlet. The problem is though status for the document is in pending state, the workflow is not started. Below is my code.

```
                Folder folder = null;
//  getting folder
                try {

                folder =    DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(10181, 0, folderName);
                System.out.println("getting folder");
                } catch(NoSuchFolderException e)
                {
//                  creating folder
                    System.out.println("creating folder");
                    try {
                        folder = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFolder(userId, 10181, 0, folderName, description, serviceContext);

                    } catch (PortalException e3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SystemException e3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                catch (PortalException e4) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e4.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SystemException e4) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e4.printStackTrace();
                }


//                  adding file

                    try {
                        System.out.println("New File");

fileEntry = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(userId,
                                10181, folder.getFolderId(), sourceFileName,
                                mimeType, title, "testing description",
                                "changeLog", sampleChapter, serviceContext);

Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
workflowContext.put("event",DLSyncConstants.EVENT_CHECK_IN);

DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(userId, fileEntry.getFileVersion().getFileVersionId(), WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH, workflowContext, serviceContext);
System.out.println("after entry"+ fileEntry.getFileEntryId());

                    } catch (DuplicateFileException e) {

                            } catch (PortalException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (SystemException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (PortalException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SystemException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

            return fileEntry.getFileEntryId();

    }
```

I have even used `WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance(companyId, userId, fileEntry.getClass().getName(), fileEntry.getClassPK, fileEntry, serviceContext);`
But still i have the same problem

Comment: Could you please clean up code a bit (and extract the lines responsible for adding the file)? The issue doesn't seem to be hard to solve but it's really hard to read that code.

Comment: Very bad code to read. In general do not use `DLAppLocalServiceUtil` but `DLAppServiceUtil`

Comment: Sorry for pasting the entire code. actually i was trying with many ways

Comment: Hope this code is readable

Comment: @DanieleBaggio I tried with DLAppServiceUtil but after uploading it's not visible in document and media portlet

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on DMS service for upload document and media in Liferay Dxp.
By default **status** of the document will be **draft**.You can use below code,

```
         DLFileEntry dlFileEntry = null;
         String fileName = null;
         long PARENT_FOLDER_ID = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;
         DLFolder folder = DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(group.getGroupId(), PARENT_FOLDER_ID,
                        "SirswaPartnerDocuments");
                long groupId = folder.getGroupId();
                long repositoryId = folder.getRepositoryId();
                long folderId = folder.getFolderId();
                String sourceFileName = "dummy";
                String mimeType = MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file);
                String title = file.getName();
                String extension = "Caption";
                fileName = file.getName();

            String uniqueTitle = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getUniqueTitle(groupId, folderId,
                    folder.getDefaultFileEntryTypeId(), title, extension);

            String changeLog = "SirswaChangeLog";
            String description = folder.getDescription();
            long defaultFileEntryTypeId = folder.getDefaultFileEntryTypeId();
        try
         {
            dlFileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(folder.getUserId(), groupId,
            repositoryId, folder.getFolderId(), sourceFileName, MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file),
            uniqueTitle, description, changeLog, folder.getDefaultFileEntryTypeId(),
            ddmFormValuesMap, file, is, size, serviceContext);

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now if you want to change the status of document and media **draft** to **Approved** programmatically.

Use below code It will work as expected

```
 int workFlowStatus = WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED;

                        dlFileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(folder.getUserId(),dlFileEntry.getFileVersion().getFileVersionId(),workFlowStatus, serviceContext,new HashMap<String, Serializable>());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of code that insert correctly fileentry into document library. Take care the `serviceContext` settings.

```
                    ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
                    serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true);
                    serviceContext.setUserId(userDest.getUserId());
                    serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(userDest.getGroupId());
                    serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH);

                    FileEntry newfile =
                        DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(
                            userDest.getUserId(),
                            userDest.getGroupId(),
                            folder.getFolderId(),
                            item.getFileName(),
                            MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(item.getFileName()),
                            item.getFileName(), null, null, bytes,
                            serviceContext);
```

Comment: I tried with the same thing but I get stackoverflow error. and file is not getting added.

Comment: serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(10181);
serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true);
serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);  serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH);
serviceContext.setAssetEntryVisible(true); serviceContext.setUserId(userId);

Comment: I dont know how to paste the error log here. Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source) this is   at com.liferay.portal.json.jabsorb.serializer.LiferaySerializer.canSerialize(LiferaySerializer.java:52)
 at org.jabsorb.JSONSerializer.getSerializer(JSONSerializer.java:818) at org.jabsorb.JSONSerializer.marshall(JSONSerializer.java:387)
 at org.jabsorb.serializer.impl.BeanSerializer.marshall(BeanSerializer.java:240)

Comment: Strange error log, but i need the full stack trace. Use gist.github.com, paste the log, give us the link..

Comment: sorry the url was wrong. please find the correct url https://gist.github.com/rajilion/c9e48eeed494ac343dc5#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: I saw the log with gist. I don't understand what you are doing. Why are you using json Web service?

Comment: I am uploading files using json webservice. It is working fine when I use action_draft, the problem comes only when I use action_publish